# Mongo aggregate query $sort before $group taking a lot of time

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need some data for a user sorted by time and grouped by the phone numbers.
Used $match followed by $sort and then $group.
The query is talking a lot of time  on mongo.
If i remove any one of the $sort or $group criteria the query executes within milli secs.

the query i am using is

```
db.buyerResponse.aggregate([
    { $match: { superProfileId: 321956, responseDate: { $gte: new Date(1432739021103), $lt: new Date(1448636621103) } } }, 
    { $sort: { responseDate: -1 } },
    { $group: { _id: "$phone", responseId: { $first: "$_id" } }}, { $skip: 0 }, 
    { $limit: 50 }
])
```

Comment: It takes 11 seconds for collection size of 15 millions document. Also it gives result in around 100 msec if i remove soting. Also all the fields of above query are indexed.

Comment: Show us! You might have a problem with the index or indices (in case you bet on intersection).

Comment: How much time does it take if your sort first and then match?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg superProfileId, responseDate and phone all are indexed

Comment: @Amar ***Show*** us, please. Single or multiple? Order? Simply ***show*** us.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg  db.collect.getIndexes()
[
 {
  "v" : 1,
  "key" : {
   "_id" : 1
  },
  "name" : "_id_",
  "ns" : "mydb.collect"
 },
 {
  "v" : 1,
  "key" : {
   "superProfileId" : 1
  },
  "name" : "superProfileId",
  "ns" : "mydb.collect"
 },
 {
  "v" : 1,
  "key" : {
   "phone" : 1
  },
  "name" : "phone",
  "ns" : "mydb.collect"
 },
 {
  "v" : 1,
  "key" : {
   "responseDate" : 1
  },
  "name" : "responseDate",
  "ns" : "mydb.collect"
 },

Answer (score 2):

You should group before sorting. Once you group, there are a lot less records to sort. Generally, you almost always want to sort last.

Comment: This might help but i have read on mongodb site that sort before group helps in proper usage of indexes.
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/

Comment: Also I have a use case that needs sorting before group

Comment: Are you indexing by responseDate?